# How to build associative array with the same/duplicated keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have couple of elements:

```
<fieldset data-filter-type="services" data-filter="contract">
<fieldset data-filter-type="services" data-filter="mortgage">
<fieldset data-filter-type="services" data-filter="valuation">
```

From this elements i'm trying to build associative array to sent some filters to server, so i do this:

```
var filters = {};

filtersContainer.find('fieldset').each(function() {
    filters[$(this).data('filter-type')] = $(this).data('filter');
    return filters;
});
```

The array is building but with only one element - the last one `filters[services]:valuation`. I think that is because each of this elements has the same key value which is `services`. How to build array with all objects?

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON? What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do something like this instead:

```
var filters = [];

filtersContainer.find('fieldset').each(function() {
    filters.push([$(this).data('filter-type'), $(this).data('filter')]);
});
```

Associative arrays (objects), by definition, can't have duplicate keys.

Comment: wird, this split data to `filters[0][]:services filters[0][]:contract`

Comment: It's different.  You'll end up with an array of arrays.  Each item in the top-level array will be another array with two items.  The first item specifies the filter type.  The second specifies the filter value.  By the way, the value of `filters` in your original example is usually referred to as an object.  It may also be called an associative array but, in the context of javascript, that's confusing.

Comment: so :) what i need to do?

Comment: If it's still not clear what I'm recommending, I'd suggest you sit with it for a while and see if you can come to an understanding about it.

Comment: and what is your problem?